# Submitted a pull request, which was merged, now I need to update my fork

Tags: git, fork, pull-request

Here is what I did:

1. Forked a repo
2. Created new feature branch on my fork
3. Submitted PR to original repo master (accepted, merged)

Next How Do I:

1. Update "master" in my own fork?

Comment: Is this on GitHub / Bitbucket? There's a button for bringing your fork up to date with the original.

Comment: yes the PR was accepted and merged, OP corrected

Comment: Well so just ask your fork to update.

Comment: If you want to do it locally, complete instructions here: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork

Comment: Why do you need to update master of your fork?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328058/git-how-to-re-syc-a-fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the relevant operation is [fork synchronization](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork):

1. [Add the upstream remote](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork), call it "upstream"
2. git fetch from the upstream remote

   ```
   git fetch upstream
   ```
3. check out "master" from my fork

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
4. merge the upstream master (which now has my accepted changes) into my master

   ```
   git merge upstream/master
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Below two commands will update your local master branch.

`git checkout master`

`git pull`